# iOS notification control?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some questions about FCM (Google Cloud Message) on iOS.

1.
The server sends the message `ABC` to the client, but can the client change the content to `AAA`?

2.
The notification works normally in the background, but not in the foreground. Is there a way to work in the foreground?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on how you pop up the notification, you can trigger a new local notification with message AAA, upon receiving a message ABC.
2. For iOS10+, have you check with

   userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)?

which you have to call the completionHandler in order to pop up the message when the app is running in foreground.

> If your app is in the foreground when a notification arrives, the notification center calls this method to deliver the notification directly to your app. If you implement this method, you can take whatever actions are necessary to process the notification and update your app. When you finish, execute the completionHandler block and specify how you want the system to alert the user, if at all.
>   If your delegate does not implement this method, the system silences alerts as if you had passed the UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone option to the completionHandler block. If you do not provide a delegate at all for the UNUserNotificationCenter object, the system uses the notification’s original options to alert the user.

fyi: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter